# I want to set sort function default as DESC but error is Occuring in php

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

Hello I am trying to add different sort function in my code . so added sorting by asecending and descending,  but i am trying to add in code is that when there is no value selected it should be in DESCENDING order By DEFAULT. and when it select the value it should show in the Drop Down meun Which value is selected. suppose user select descending then it should show Descending in box. here Is my code.

Here is MY PHP code

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "videoplay";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
} 
  
$limit = 20;  
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };  
$start_from = ($page-1) * $limit;  
$name = $_GET['name'];
$sort = $_GET['sort'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM video where type= 'Video/Trailer' IF  ORDER BY vid  ".$sort." IS NULL THEN SET DESC  AS DEFAULT LIMIT $start_from, $limit";  
$rs_result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
?>
```

```html
<form action="#">
<select class="select" onChange="top.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value="<?php echo $value ; ?>" selected="<?php echo $selected; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></option>
<option  name="Ascending" value="videos.php?sort=ASC">Ascending </option>
<option name="Descending" value="videos.php?sort=DESC">Descending</option>
  
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: Why not checking if GET['sort'] is empty|null, than set your default value of $sort to DESC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "videoplay";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    } 

    $limit = 20;  
    if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };  
    $start_from = ($page-1) * $limit;  
    $name = $_GET['name'];

    $sort = isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : "DESC";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM video WHERE type = 'Video/Trailer' ORDER BY vid $sort LIMIT $start_from, $limit";  
    $rs_result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
?>
```

You can use basic ternary operator to check if the `sort` is sent.

```
$sort = isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : "DESC";
```

Ternary operator is made from three parts: comparison, true comparison, false comparison.

1. `isset($_GET['sort'])` - Comparison: Is `sort` sent?
2. `$_GET['sort']` - True comparison: If **it is** then assign it to the `$sort` variable.
3. `"DESC"` - False comparison: If **it's not** then assign the default `DESC` value.

I also removed unnecessary things from your query.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM video 
        WHERE type = 'Video/Trailer' 
        ORDER BY vid $sort 
        LIMIT $start_from, $limit";
```

---

It has to be mentioned that you should use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent the SQL injection.

Comment: Please Explain What You Have Modified In The Code. It's Hard To Understand The Changes Done By You.

Comment: @PavanChanda I updated my answer once again. I'm glad it works and make sure to use my latest code. It would be cool if you could vote up and accept as correct answer :).

Comment: @Spectarion how to show selected sort option in html code its not showing